# Optional promise-step based on query parameter

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I've got a function retrieving blog-posts from the database. The same function is used for blog-posts of a certain category. This is the query:

```
Post.find( params ).limit(5)
```

However when a category shall be looked up, the id of the category has to be retrieved first (the query-param is its permalink):

```
Category.findOne({ permalink: req.params.category})
```

How can I use promises to prevent having to write something duplicate like this:

```
// a category is present
if (typeof req.params.category !== 'undefined'){
  Category.findOne({ permalink: req.params.category}).then(function(category){
    params.category = category.id
    Post.find(params).limit(5).exec(function(err,posts){
      // yada-yada
    })
  }
}
// no category
else {
  Post.find(params).limit(5).exec(function(err,posts){
    // yada-yada
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with this solution assuming that you have access to the [BuiltIn Promise Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
Promise.resolve(req.params.category)
  .then(function (categoryParam) {
    if (categoryParam) {
      // if you return a promise then the `then` function stored in the
      // previous promise will be executed when this promise (the one returned
      // here) is resolved
      return Category
        .findOne({ permalink: categoryParam})
        .then(function (category) {
          return category.id;
        });
    } else {
       // nothing to do here so the resolution value of this promise is undefined
    }
  })
  .then(function (categoryId) {
      if (categoryId) {
        // checks the existance of the categoryId
        params.category = categoryId;
      }

      Post
        .find(params)
        .limit(5)
        .exec(function(err,posts){
          // yada-yada
        })
  })
```

Let me explain the solution above:

1. Let's start with an promise whose resolution value is the `category` param of the request
2. If the param exists than means that we have to make a query to find a category based on the param before making the `Post` request, in most implementations of promises I've seen if you return a promise from a `.then` then the `.then` callbacks stored in the previous promise will be executed whenever the returning value is fulfilled, (I haven't tested with the builtIn Promise object but for example `q` from KrisKowal is able to resolve any promise-like objects) which is the case here since I don't know about the promise structure that `Category.findOne({ permalink: categoryParam})` returns, in any case when the query to get the category is complete the fulfilling value of the returning promise will be the category's id
3. In the final `then` we have to check if the `categoryId` param exists (it may have been returned from the previous `then`), if so then update the `params` object with it

Comment: He's using bluebird promises which means he's using a faster superset.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a promise for the `params` - either from that category-id request or by simply using [`Promise.resolve`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promiseresolvedynamic-value---promise) when that is not needed. Then, you can trivially chain your `find` call on that:

```
((typeof req.params.category !== 'undefined')
  ? Category.findOne({permalink: req.params.category}).then(function(category){
        params.category = category.id
        return params;
    })
  : Promise.resolve(params)
).then(function(p) {
    return Post.find(p).limit(5).exec();
}).then(function(posts) {
    // yada-yada
});
```